# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTranslation' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I just call `this.sendTranslation`. I thought it might have been the `e.preventDefault()` line, but it's not. What's wrong and how do I call `sendTranslation` from within `Popup.checkIfEnterPressed`?

```
import React from "react";
import "../../styles/popup.css";

export default class Popup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // STATE
    this.state = {
      word: "",
      translation: ""
    };
    // BINDINGS
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.sendTranslation = this.sendTranslation.bind(this);
  }

  sendTranslation() {
    // send translation to background.js
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      { wordsPair: [this.state.word, this.state.translation] },
      function(response) {
        window.close();
      }
    );
  }

  checkIfEnterPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // to prevent calling handleChange
      this.sendTranslation();
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <header>Fishky</header>
        <div className="word field">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="word"
            placeholder="Word"
            value={this.state.word}
            onKeyUp={this.checkIfEnterPressed}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="translation field">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="translation"
            placeholder="Translation/Definition"
            value={this.state.translation}
            onKeyUp={this.checkIfEnterPressed}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="submit-word">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-default btn-block"
            id="submit-popup"
            onClick={this.sendTranslation}
          >
            add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Error. Why do I get null?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTranslation' of null
    at checkIfEnterPressed (Popup.js:31)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:69)
    at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:85)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:108)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js:43)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js:54)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachAccumulated (forEachAccumulated.js:24)
    at Object.processEventQueue (EventPluginHub.js:254)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also bind this method : `checkIfEnterPressed`

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      // STATE
      this.state = {
        word: "",
        translation: ""
      };
      // BINDINGS
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.sendTranslation = this.sendTranslation.bind(this);
      this.checkIfEnterPressed = this.checkIfEnterPressed.bind(this);
    }
```